# populateViewHolder method of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter called multiple times, causing AmbiguousViewMatcherException

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-espresso, firebaseui

In my Firebase based app, I'm using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class a lot. During setup of tests I run into the problem that the `populateViewHolder` get's called multiple times for the same position (this log output shows the situation in case of 1 item in my firebase location:

```
-InstancesOverviewFragment: onCreate()
-InstancesOverviewFragment: Creating mAdapter()
-InstancesOverviewFragment: onViewCreated
-InstancesOverviewFragment: populateViewHolder for: 0, instance: Firebase model Instance: {"attendances":{"-KrGpYZA9qekLTy4LW2d"
-InstancesOverviewFragment: populateViewHolder for: 0, instance: Firebase model Instance: {"attendances":{"-KrGpYZA9qekLTy4LW2d"
-InstancesOverviewFragment: onDestroyView
-InstancesOverviewFragment: onDestroy
```

The GUI only shows 1 item (which is correct), but running Espresso tests is causing issues because they throw an `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` since there are 2 items that have equal contents. Note that this seems to be a timing issue: when adding a sleep (500ms) in the tests, the problem does not appear anymore.

My questions:

1. is it correct that the `populateViewHolder` method is being called multiple times?

2: (in case 1 is correct); what is the best practice for running Espresso test when using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`? Is it adding a short sleep?

Thanks for any help!